# Tags and file attachments on Mantis "create issue" page

Tags: tags, attachment, mantis

Does anyone know if there is a way to add tags and attachments on Mantis "create issue" page?

I´m wasting too much time adding pictures and tags after send the report by editing each one.

Comment: In my version of mantis, I have "Upload file" (attachment) on the report issue page, but not "Assign tags" -- this is important to make tagging a useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

No, right now it's not possible but feel free to file an enhancement request or to add your comment to an existing one.

Comment: For information, [this](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=9450) is the enhancement request for tagging from the Create Issue page. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent request for adding attachments.